# image is overlapping text in picker custom rendere for android

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls, picker

i have created custom renderer of picker for android.but arrow image is overlapping picker text.as shown in below screenshot

[image]

here is my code

```
 public class AndroidCutomPicker : PickerRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null && this.Element != null)
        {
            Control.Background = AddPickerStyles();
            Control.SetLines(1);
            //Control.TextSize *= 0.25f;
        }

    }

    public LayerDrawable AddPickerStyles()
    {
        ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
        border.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
        border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        border.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

        Drawable[] layers = { border, GetDrawable() };
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
        layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        return layerDrawable;
    }

    private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable()
    {
        var drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, Resource.Drawable.dropdownarrow);
        var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;

        var result = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true));
        result.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Right;

        return result;
    }

}
```

please help.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem and finding this question but finally i find a solution that is adding a padding  where you want for me the padding is related to the size of the element so i make it like this

```
 this.Control.SetPadding((int)(element.Width / 5), Control.PaddingTop, Control.PaddingRight,         Control.PaddingBottom);
```

but if u have a specific constant binding u can do like this

```
 this.Control.SetPadding(Control.PaddingLeft+XXX, Control.PaddingTop+xxx, Control.PaddingRight+xxx,         Control.PaddingBottom+xxx);
```